# SpriteKit - SpriteNode never shows

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I am attempting to learn SpriteKit.  I want to add a rectangle/square to the scene in code; but the item never shows;

All I want to do is add a white square to the screen, but find that it never adds.

In a breakpoint, I notice that didMove() never seems to get called.

What am I doing wrong?

```
class GameScene: SKScene {

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        let item = SKSpriteNode(color: .white, size: CGSize(width: 150, height: 200))
        item.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width/2, y: self.size.height/2)
        self.addChild(item)
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    }

    override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
        // Called before each frame is rendered
    }
}
```

---

update

I did not change the view controller generated by xcode

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if let view = self.view as! SKView? {
            // Load the SKScene from 'GameScene.sks'
            if let scene = SKScene(fileNamed: "GameScene") {
                // Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window
                scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill

                // Present the scene
                view.presentScene(scene)
            }

            view.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

            view.showsFPS = true
            view.showsNodeCount = true
        }
    }

    override var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
        return true
    }

    override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone {
            return .allButUpsideDown
        } else {
            return .all
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
    }

    override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

There is no GameScene.sks, I deleted this file as I do not want to use sks files

Comment: try `item.zPosition = 100` and change your sprite colour?. If your background is white

Comment: What color is the screens background?

Comment: have you set your `GameScene` in `GameViewController(viewDidLoad)`?.

Comment: screen bgcolor is black

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a breakpoint in didMove(to view:) is never reached, then definitely your ViewController doesn't present the scene for some reason. Can you open your ViewController's file (e.g. GameViewController.swift) and see if you have any of those lines there (or anything to that effect):

```
let viewSize = UIScreen.main.bounds.size
let scene = GameScene(size: viewSize)
let skView = self.view as! SKView
skView.presentScene(scene)
```

Comment: I replaced my view controller with your code and it displays my shape

Answer (score 0):

Turns out view controller was not presenting the scene and changing it to this, following code posted by @Stoyan worked and I saw my sprite showing

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

```
if let view = self.view as! SKView? {

    let viewSize = UIScreen.main.bounds.size
    let scene = GameScene(size: viewSize)

    view.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
    view.showsFPS = true
    view.showsNodeCount = true

    view.presentScene(scene)

}
```

Comment: Oops, I knew I had to see your view controller's code first. Now it's a mess. Let's clear it up: remove the line skView.presentScene..., also remove the let skView = ...    Then, simply add as a last line: view.presentScene(scene). Sorry about the confusion!

Comment: I tried to edit the code myself but it's now pending peer review.

Comment: ok many thanks; i do not see any notifications to approve it so am unable to do so myself; I have updated the code posted above to reflect the changes you state; I am hopeful it is now correct